Remove Char(13) and Char(10) at the end of the string using REGEXP_Replace in PLSQL
I am using ELF file to load the data to database with CTRL file. If the last field in the segment having CHAR(13) and/or CHAR(10) then the data is stored with CHAR(13) and CHAR(10). It is giving any error while processing the data.
Need to remove CHAR(13) and/or CHAR(10) if found at the end of the field in the segment.
3|1|TEST|3641203|TEST:3641203||ACTIVE|202402190032-04||AA||AA|||||||||202404100138-04|||201307310906
3|2|TESTA|3641203|Y|OFF|Y|29155000||STREET|ADD NEW|MESE|NY|12121||USA||D|||PHL||||||||TEST DATA AT THE END

Adding DESCRIPTION CHAR(200) "REPLACE(REPLACE(:DESCRIPTION, CHR(13)), CHR(10)) is removing all the spaces in the field instead it has to check the last character and remove it if found.
Please assist.

You should provide a minimum reproducible example and at least share what error you are getting.
